# MapStruct: Map List of objects, when object is mapped from two objects

Tags: java, mapping, mapstruct

Assume I have such  mapping:

```
@Mapping(source = "parentId", target = "parent.id")
Child map(ChildDto dto, Parent parent);
```

Now I need to map List of ChildDto to List of Child, but they all have the same parent. I expect to do something like that:

```
List<Child> map(List<ChildDto> dtoList, Parent parent);
```

But it doesn't working.
Is there any chance to do it?

Answer (score 7):

I found how to implement it with decorators, thanks @Gunnar
Here is an implementation:

### Beans

```
public class Child {
    int id;
    String name;
}
public class Parent {
    int id;
    String name;
}
public class ChildDto {
    int id;
    String name;
    int parentId;
    String parentName;
}
// getters/settes ommited
```

### Mapper

```
@Mapper
@DecoratedWith(ChildMapperDecorator.class)
public abstract class ChildMapper {
    public static final ChildMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(ChildMapper.class);

    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(target = "parentId", ignore = true),
            @Mapping(target = "parentName", ignore = true)
    })
    @Named("toDto")
    abstract ChildDto map(Child child);

    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true),
            @Mapping(target = "name", ignore = true),
            @Mapping(target = "parentId", source = "id"),
            @Mapping(target = "parentName", source = "name")
    })
    abstract ChildDto map(@MappingTarget ChildDto dto, Parent parent);

    @IterableMapping(qualifiedByName = "toDto") // won't work without it
    abstract List<ChildDto> map(List<Child> children);

    List<ChildDto> map(List<Child> children, Parent parent) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented");
    }
}
```

### Decorator

```
public abstract class ChildMapperDecorator extends ChildMapper {
    private final ChildMapper delegate;

    protected ChildMapperDecorator(ChildMapper delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public List<ChildDto> map(List<Child> children, Parent parent) {
        List<ChildDto> dtoList = delegate.map(children);
        for (ChildDto childDto : dtoList) {
            delegate.map(childDto, parent);
        }
        return dtoList;
    }
}
```

I use `abstract class`, not `interface` for mapper, because in case of `interface` you couldn't exclude for generation method `map(List<Child> children, Parent parent)`, and the code being generated is not valid in compile time.

Comment: I tried this, and it doesn't work. for my case i have dto with a set of children of the same dto

Answer (score 3):

I used an `@AfterMapping` as suggested by Gunnar:

```
@AfterMapping
public void afterDtoToEntity(final QuestionnaireDTO dto, @MappingTarget final Questionnaire entity) {
  entity.getQuestions().stream().forEach(question -> question.setQuestionnaire(entity));
}
```

This made sure all the questions were linked to the same questionnaire entity. This was the final part of the solution for avoiding the JPA error `save the transient instance before flushing` on creating a new parent entity with a list of children.

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible out of the box as things stand. You could use a decorator or after-mapping method to set the parent to all the child objects afterwards.

Comment: Please look at my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37796378/2482449 Does it seems like what you meant?