# Mapstruct Invoking implicitly other mapper with multiple parameter

Tags: java, mapstruct

Given the following classes and a mapper that takes mulitple source arguments

(I use lombok to keep source as short as possible.)

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class MySourceOne {
  private String src1;
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class MySourceTwo {
  private String src2;
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class MyTargetObject {
  private String prop1;
  private String prop2;
}

@Mapper
public interface MyTargetObjectMapper {
  @Mapping(target="prop1", source="a")
  @Mapping(target="prop2", source="b")
  public MyTargetObject mapMyObject(String a, String b);
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class MyComplexTargetObject {
  private MyTargetObject myTargetObject;
}
```

I am trying to create a mapper for `MyComplexTargetObject` that will invoke implicitly the `MyTargetObjectMapper` .

But the "source" won't allow to map multiple parameter like this

```
@Mapper(uses= {MyTargetObjectMapper.class})
public interface MyComplexTargetObjectMapper {
  @Mapping(target="myTargetObject", source="one.src1, two.src2")
  public MyComplexTargetObject convert(MySourceOne one, MySourceTwo two);
}
```

So I am trying to use an `expression="..."` instead of source, but nothing works so far.

Any thoughts a clean way to do this **without calling the `MyTargetObjectMapper` in a concrete method?**

Comment: You can do https://stackoverflow.com/a/37796378/1136671

Answer (score 1):

MapStruct does not support selection of methods with multiple sources.

However: you can do target nesting to do this.

```java
@Mapper
public interface MyComplexTargetObjectMapper {

    @Mapping(target="myTargetObject.prop1", source="one.src1" )
    @Mapping(target="myTargetObject.prop2", source="two.src2")
    public MyComplexTargetObject convert(MySourceOne one, MySourceTwo two);
}
```

And let MapStruct take care of generating the mapper. Note: you can still use a `MyComplexTargetObjectMapper` to do single source to target to achieve this.